# Should I use async await on UI Thread or Task.Run to process multiple files?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, .net-4.5

I am writing an application in WPF using .NET 4.5. The application allows the user to select multiple files and import them. When this happens the application will parse text files and store the data into a database. The files can be very large so I want the UI to remain responsive and allow the user to do other things while this is happening.

I'm new to asynchronous programming and would to know what the best approach would be? According to a [Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)...

> "The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be created. Async methods don't require multithreading because an async method doesn't run on its own thread. The method runs on the current synchronization context and uses time on the thread only when the method is active. You can use Task.Run to move CPU-bound work to a background thread, but a background thread doesn't help with a process that's just waiting for results to become available."

Since I am processing multiple files would I be better of using "Task.Run" for each file since they will run on separate threads? If not, what is the advantage of running everything on the same thread using async/await?

Note that no other UI operation (except progress bars - progress reporting) really cares about when these files are done processing so according to this article it seems like using Task.Run would benefit me. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you doing with the files? If you're doing anything CPU intensive, it would be better to move that processing off the UI thread. If it's really just going to be the IO, then you can do it all in the UI thread - and *still* make it parallel.

For example:

```
private async Task ProcessAllFiles(IEnumerable<string> files)
{
    List<Task> tasks = files.Select(x => ProcessFile(x))
                            .ToList();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    textBox.Text = "Finished!";
}

private async Task ProcessFile(string file)
{
    // Do stuff here with async IO, and update the UI if you want to...
}
```

Here you're still doing all the actual processing on the UI thread - no separate threads are running, beyond potentially IO completion ports - but you're still starting multiple asynchronous IO operations at the same time.

Now one other thing to consider is that this *might* actually slow everything down anyway. If you're processing multiple files on the same physical disk, you might find that accessing them sequentially would be faster just due to the nature of disk IO. It will depend on the disk type though (SSDs would act differently to "regular" disks, for example).

Comment: Thanks, those are some good points. Basically I'm parsing several text files (each on the order of 5-10MB in size) into rows and columns of data and using Entity Framework to store this new data into a database. So lots of string.split, converting strings to data types, and database inserts. As far as I know the majority of users will have conventional disk drives (not solid state).

Comment: @akagixxer: Well, the database inserts will probably be the vast majority of that time - and they can be asynchronous. If you make `ProcessFile` a method returning a `Task`, you can always change between that kicking off a task with `Task.Run` or just using asynchronous IO... the rest of the code won't need to care. I'd try it both ways if I were you - but it's important to understand the idea that you can still get parallel operations using a single thread, if those operations aren't CPU-bound.

Comment: Okay. From the tests I have already done the parsing and database inserts are definitely the bottleneck. I suppose I can try each way out and see how it goes.

Comment: @akagixxer: Aside from anything else, I'm sure doing this sort of experiment will make you more comfortable with async stuff :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Using your answer I converted my Parallel.Foreach to run on the Ui and it works great except in the TPL we have maxdegreeofparallelism, I need something similar here as I need to restrict max tasks (as each one is calling a web service and there is a max of 8) Any suggestions or pointers how I can acheive this?

Comment: @TinoMclaren: You might want to look at TPL Dataflow.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thank you kindly