# How do you make the application wait and keep other processes running at the same time in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sleep, wait

Using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( ) makes the entire application stop for the time taken in the arguments. I want other processes running while one process is waiting for a particular amount of time. To put it in short, I want another way other than System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( ) in my application that does not stop the entire thing.

Example: If I have a label that changes text every 5 seconds, I should be able to press a button which can do some other process, like changing an image.

Comment: This question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180422/async-await-on-ui-thread-vs-task-run-multiple-file-processing

Comment: Thread.Sleep() only puts the current thread to sleep. It looks like you are calling it on the UI thread.. The common practice is to let UI thread take care of the rendering and keep all your processing in separate threads.

Comment: If you make the GUI thread sleep, the app will be unresponsive.  Are you sure you are having the right thread sleep?

Comment: Perhaps showing a minimal effort would be useful to point us in the right direction.

Comment: I just gave an example, and I do understand that the example is not informative enough. Let's see. Here's another example:

Comment: There are two labels, and BOTH of them change every five seconds. I want to use two different chunks of code to make the second label change text when the first label is not changing text.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.Sleep()` only puts the current thread to sleep. If it is the UI thread, this might block your application and it looks like it is completely blocked. Background threads are still running.

If you want to sleep without blocking, you could use the following code:

```
await Task.Delay(5000);
// continue here with your code, such as updating your label
```

This doesn't block the UI thread, just delays the proceeding of your function. You have to declare your method as `async`

Answer (score 0):

I am not too informed about this so I am not sure this is the best way to do it

[The Task.Wait Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635(v=vs.110).aspx)

like that your main thread waits for the child thread to complete before continuing. From here on to your problem I guess just brains will help

an other helpful link:

[Thread Synchronization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx)

Comment: Task.Wait() stopps until the specified task terminates. It is not the same as Sleep, which delays the current thread.

Comment: that's what I wrote, just nicer phrased.  And as OP has said it should, the Wait funktion DOES wait for a specific time without stopping the entire thing.

Comment: I dont think, your answer is correct. Task.Wait() is something completely different than Thread.Sleep(). It waits until ANOTHER thread is completed and the current thread IS blocked in the meantime. It does NOT wait for a specific time.